# Fixed length integers in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to set a fixed length for integers. For example, `001`. Is there any function to get this done? Thanks in advance

Comment: there are no leading zeros in an integer.  If you are referring to formatting for display see here - https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to process the integer values with proceeding zeroes. Is that possible?

Comment: What do you mean by process the values?

Comment: There is no such thing other than a number represented as a string.  So you can have the string "0000000001"  when converted to an int, it is just 1.You are confusing the internal representation of an int with its external representation  some more details in the question is needed.

Comment: If you want to control how `int`s are formatted when converted to `String`s, you can use [`int.toStringAsFixed`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.2/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html).  If you want to parse such strings, then you don't need to do anything special: `int.parse` (or `int.tryParse`) will handle leading `0`s in the string, and you could add your own check to verify if the string is of the required length.

Answer (score 4):

To someone who is googling the answer...

```
 String intFixed(int n, int count) => n.toString().padLeft(count, "0");
 print(intFixed(3, 3)); // 003
```